# Google Finance gain value incorrect because of currency fluctuation

Tags: currency, usd-us-dollar, eur-euro, google-finance

I'm french, and I bought some stocks in Paris and New York Stock Exchanges. I'm trying to use an online portfolio tracking tool like Google Finance, but the final gain value is incorrect because of currency fluctuation.

Let take a simple example : I have a share of a company X which I bought $100 with a €/$ rate of 0.87, so I payed 87€.
Now, the share is worth $102 and the €/$ rate is now 0.85.
So the current value is 102 * 0.85 = 86.70€, and i'm loosing 0.30€.

But Google finance is not taking the share buying conversion rate, so it calculate like this :

gain = ($102 - $100) * 0.85 = +1.7€

but the good calculation should be :

gain = ($102 * 0.85) - ($100 * 0.87) = -0.3€

Did I miss anything, or is it impossible to do what I want in Google Finance ? And if it is not possible do you know any other website or Android app that allow conversion rate input ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does google finance allow you to record transactions on USD traded securities in other currencies?  If I had to guess, I'd say google finance doesn't support this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily build a Google Sheet spreadsheet to track what you want as Sheet has a 'googlefinance()' function to look-up the same prices and data you can enter and track in a Google Finance portfolio, except you can use it in ways you want.

For example, you can track your purchase price at a fixed exchange rate, track the current market value as the product of the stock's price times the floating exchange rate, and then record your realized profit and loss using another fixed exchange rate.  You don't have to record the rates either, as googlefinance() func is able to lookup prices as of a particular date.

You can access Google Sheet through a web browser or Android app.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, I was searching if an existing tool was able to to that but I guess no... But I don't need to use googlefinance() to get the old rate, because I have the € and $ prices I paid so I can calculate it myself. But thanks anyway :)